# syntax error unexpected '}' at 364 line

Tags: php, functions, errors, parse

I am getting this error on my website and am not able to access admin dashboard. The error occurs when I am a new theme on my website. Can you please help me to find this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/content/html/wp-content/themes/imag-mag/functions.php on line 364

Comment: You've got an extra closing `}` somewhere in your `functions.php` file.  If you're writing the theme yourself, you'll need to debug it.  Without seeing more code for context, there's not a lot that others can tell you.

Comment: The extra closing `}` is at line 364 of `functions.php`, so try removing it, or commenting it out e.g. `//}` - if you're not confident in removing things from your code AND then run your process again to see if any other errors are thrown. Usually, if that extra `}` was critical to a function, conditional statement or control structure you would get an error thrown higher up in your chain of execution indicating such.

Comment: Show us `functions.php` content.